# How to stop/close a Twitter API Filtered Stream after x seconds?

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, twitterapi-python

I just wanted to know how to stop a Twitter API Filtered Steam after x seconds.

I have got this so far:

```
t_end = time.time() + 10

while time.time() < t_end:
    bearer_token = config.BEARER_TOKEN
    headers = create_headers(bearer_token)
    rules = get_rules(headers, bearer_token)
    delete = delete_all_rules(headers, bearer_token, rules)
    set = set_rules(headers, delete, bearer_token)
    get_stream(headers, set, bearer_token)
print("ended")
```

However, the stream just continues. I cannot seem to find in the Twitter API documentation how to close a stream or ways to close a stream.

Answer (score 0):

By it is meaning, [streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media) is intended to transmit and recieve data in a continuous flow. However, in python you can use libraries to stop it.

One way is to use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), you start to count the time while you are streaming and abort the python file after some time:

```
# after building your arguments like bearer token and rules

def manage_streaming():
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=get_stream, args=(headers, set, bearer_token,))
    thread1.start()
    sleep(time_2_end_in_seconds)
    print('ended')
    break  # or you can use sys.exit() directly here to stop the 
           # executing file.
```